# How do I return a partial view from my controller to display on my main view?

Tags: c#, asp.net, kendo-ui

I have the view:

```
<div>
    <form method="post"action='@Url.Action("ImportProviders")'>
        @(Html.Kendo().Upload()
            .Name("files")
            .HtmlAttributes(new { aria_label = "files" })
            .Validation(validation => validation.AllowedExtensions(new string[] { ".csv" }))
        )
        <p class ="text"> This File Browser only Accepts .CSV File.</p>
        <input type="hidden" id="clientNumber" name="Clientid" value="" />
        <p class="submit-btn">
            <input type="submit" value="Upload Providers" onclick="submit" id="UploadClick" class="k-button k-primary" />
            <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-3x fa-fw" id="makeMeDisappear"></i>
            <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
        </p>
    </form>
</div>
<br />

<div>
    @Html.Partial("ImportedProviderView");
</div>
```

I have the c# Controller:

```
public PartialViewResult ImportProviders(String ClientId, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files) {
    ...
    ImportProvidersView(result,FaultyRowsTable,"FAULTY ROW");
    ImportProvidersView(result, InsertedRows, "INSERTED ROW");
    ImportProvidersView(result, UpdatedRowsTable, "UPDATED ROW");

    return PartialView("ImportedProviderView", result.OrderByDescending(x=>x.Createdon));
}
```

But everytime I run this page it takes me to the partial view only, it doesn't inject it into the main view above.

**MAIN QUESTION**
How do I make it display inside the main view above?

Comment: you'd need to use ajax for that.

Answer (score 0):

The `@Html.Partial` method is only going to render the partial view.  If you need to execute the controller action that returns the view you will need to use the `@Html.Action` method

```
<div>
    @Html.Action("ImportProviders", "ControllerName", new { ClientId = <>, files = <> })
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`@Html.Partial` renders the partial view on the server as part of the main view, which is returned to the browser. If you need something dynamic when the user does something in the browser then you'll probably want to GET/POST to a controller action rendering a new view - or you'll want to call a controller action rendering a partial view using ajax.